# How to use variables with regex search in re.sub()?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string and I want to get rid of multiple phrases in one pass.

If the phrase starts with "aPPle" or "pEAr" and ends with " f " or " g " (with the space characters), respectively, then I want to replace it with a space. It can have anything between the start and end.

```
segment_start = ['aPPle', 'pEAr']
segment_end = [' f ', ' g ']

j=0
while (j+1) <= len(segment_start):
    clean = re.sub(r''+segment_start[j].*segment_end[j],'',clean)
    j += 1
```

I'm stuck on getting re.sub to use the variables and I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. This is probably really simple, I've been unable to find an answer poking around SE.

Here are phrases I would remove

`aPPle increased in other categories such as f`

`pEAr !!@#!@#!@WDWDdaseio g`

Here are phrases I would keep

`aPPle t returns between paragraphsf` (no spaces enclosing `f`)

`pEAr !!@#!@#!@WDWDdaseio f` (`aPPle` goes with `f` and pEAr goes with `g`)

Comment: Please provide some positive and negative test cases so it is clear. Do you remove a phrase if, for example, it starts with "aPPle" but ends with "g"?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to *inject* values into your pattern, i.e.:

```
segment_start = ['aPPle', 'pEAr']
segment_end = [' f ', ' g ']

for i, start in enumerate(segment_start):
    clean = re.sub('{}.*{}'.format(start, segment_end[i]), ' ', clean)
```

You can do a simple `start + '.*' + segment_end[i]` instead but it becomes very unwieldy to deal with such manual concatenation if you want to employ complex patterns.

Keep in mind that your end pattern must match exactly for it to work - for example, if your string ends with `g` (no space at the end), your pattern for `pEAr` won't work. You can define it's `segment_end` as `g(\s|$)` instead to capture such case.